230V 3-Phase Power Supply for VFD and PSU Repair
I am repairing CNC electronics and need some lab equipment. I need a 3-phase, 230 V input for the power supply and VFD to debug them. Where should I look to get a supply for this? Is there something I could build or buy that could turn 120 V single phase into a 230 V, 3-phase output for my PSU and VFD?

How about a working VFD?

A VFD might get upset on driving anything other than a motor. VFDs will rectify the three phases to get one DC bus, so you could just use a 120->230V transformer. You won’t be able to test at full load as your 120V supply likely has limited current.

Thanks for responding, sir. I need 3p 230V. Maybe I am misunderstanding what you are saying. I’m not sure what you mean: use a transformer to convert 1p to 3p 230V?
Could a 120V in, 3p 230V out VFD be used as a bench power supply to power on a 3p 230V input PSU and 3p 230V input motor driver? (I wont be powering any motors just diagnosing and check voltages etc.)

One can run a three-phase motor on one-phase current, by
applying a bit of phase-shifted current for starting (to
give the three-phase motor a direction of rotation).
The windings of the three-phase motor will then act as
a generator of the three phases.
This kind of object is called a rotary power converter,
and is commercially available.   It does make noise, and
is heavy, but they're very simple and reliable.
An alternative, if you might have high current requirements,
is to get your power utility to deliver the three phases
to your site, with associated cost to rewire and a new
power meter.

Thanks Whit3rd this looks like it.
